# HTMLAgilityPack link and description extraction

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

What i have this the follow code

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")) 
{ 
    HtmlAttribute attrib = link.Attributes["href"]; hTags.Add(att.Value);
}
```

This pulls the `Href` perfectly but I would also like to pull the description of the href

Example

```
<a href="/users/logout?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask">log out</a>
```

so I already get `/users/logout?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask` but i would also like to get `log out`

result:

`/users/logout?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask | log out`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want soemthing like:

```
hTags.Add(att.Value + " | " + link.InnerText);
```